# Does postgres "SELECT FOR UPDATE" restrict to create new foreign key references ?

Tags: postgresql, locking

There are two tables, one is referenced by another with foreign key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE record
(
  id                    UUID PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL
);    

CREATE TABLE task
(
  id                    UUID PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
  record_id       UUID,
  CONSTRAINT fk_task_record_id FOREIGN KEY (record_id) 
  REFERENCES record (id)
);
```

The question is : if lock on `record` row is aquired by

```
SELECT * FROM record where id = 'A' FOR UPDATE OF record
```

Could I create new foreign key in `task` table and reference this very `record` row 
?

```
INSERT INTO task VALUES ('someId', 'A');
```

Does Postgres prevent creating new foreign key references on  tables locked by `SELECT FOR UPDATE OF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not.

`select .. for update` only blocks *changes* (update, delete) to that row.

It does not prevent other transactions from *reading* that row and that's what is required to insert a row *referencing* the locked row.

Comment: Could you suggest the way to prevent from creating new references except for locking entire table ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

Connect to your postgres database in 2 different terminals, and run the following queries in terminal 1 -

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM record where id = 'A' FOR UPDATE OF record;
```

In terminal 2, run -

```
INSERT INTO task VALUES ('someId', 'A');
```

Again in terminal 1, run -

```
COMMIT;
```

You will notice that the query in terminal 2 does not return till you do a commit in Terminal 1. This is because the for update keyword makes the query wait even for tables that reference it using a foreign key.